# Specifying --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver in conda YAML file

Tags: pip, conda

I'm creating an environment in an Azure DevOps pipeline from a .yml file. However, one of my modules has dependency issues, causing `conda env create -n env-name --file conda.yml` to get stuck. I know that I need to use `--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver` but since I'm creating the environment from a YAML file I don't know how to specify it in my YAML file (rather than directly running `pip install`).

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults

dependencies:
    - python=3.9.12
    - pip>=19.0
    - pip:
        - numpy==1.22.0
        - pandavro 
        - scikit-learn 
        - ipykernel
        - pyspark
        - mlflow
        - mltable
```

I've tried adding `[--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver]` after one of my modules (e.g. `pandavro [--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver]`) but it seems like Conda doesn't recognize this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this feature hasn't yet been implemented, based on these posts:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3763

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6805

The workaround that worked for me was removing all pip dependencies from my *conda.yml* file (i.e. all lines beginning with and including `-pip:`) and instead putting them in a separate *requirements.txt* file. I then added another step to my ADO pipeline to run `pip install -r requirements.txt --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver`.